# Images in markdown preview aren't always shown in proper location

Tags: bug, images, markdown-preview

Images in markdown preview aren't always shown in proper location.

[Example](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/127458/5656):

Markdown preview: `1.` comes before the image.

[image]

Actual location after posting/editing: `1.` is next to the image

[image]

Comment: I came across that as well. Quoting the image with `> ` fixes it.